# Simplify $\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i { n \choose i } (n - i)^3$

Tags: combinatorics

How can we simplify $\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i { n \choose i } (n - i)^3$?

I started computing the first values to figure the pattern:

$\sum_{i=0}^0(-1)^i { 0 \choose i } (0 - i)^3 = 0$

$\sum_{i=0}^1(-1)^i { 1 \choose i } (1 - i)^3 = 1 + 0 = 1$

$\sum_{i=0}^2(-1)^i { 2 \choose i } (2 - i)^3 = 2^3 - 2 + 0 = 6$

$\sum_{i=0}^3(-1)^i { 3 \choose i } (3 - i)^3 = 3^3 -3 \cdot 2^3+3-0 = 6 $

The results don't lead to a pattern and so I thought I must be missing something.

I know that $\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i { n \choose i } = 0$ but this also doesn't help.

How to go forth here to solve this (finding a form without the $\Sigma$)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will re-index the sum for personal taste.

The trick here, from the theory of generating functions, is to write $k^3$ as the linear differential operator $(x\frac{\partial}{\partial x})$ applied thrice to the power $x^k$, then evaluated at $x=1$. Then

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}k^3=\left(x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^3\left.\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}x^k\right|_{x=1} $$

$$ = \left.\left(x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^3 (x-1)^n\right|_{x=1} $$

Funnily enough, if $n>3$ then all of the derivatives of $(x-1)^n$ above (using the product rule multiple times) will still retain a $(x-1)$ factor, and so when evaluated at $x=1$ will yield $\Sigma=0$. You will see this pattern if you evaluate the sum for $n=4,5,6,\cdots$ (you will get $0$ each time)!

Answer (score 5):

The result is related to the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind):
$$
n!{3 \brace n}.
$$
Particularly for $n>3$ all values are $0$.

Answer (score 4):

First note that, for $n\ge 3$,
$${ n \choose i }i(i-1)(i-2)=n(n-1)(n-2){ n-3 \choose i-3 }.$$

So, for $n\ge 4$,
$$\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i { n \choose i } i(i-1)(i-2)=-n(n-1)(n-2)\sum_{j=0}^{n-3}(-1)^j { {n-3} \choose{j} }=0.$$
Similarly
$$\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i { n \choose i } i(i-1)=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i { n \choose i } i=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i { n \choose i }=0.$$
Therefore, by expanding $(n-i)^3$,
$$\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i { n \choose i } (n-i)^3=0.$$